# Why is the left margin jumping up?

Tags: css-float, margin, css

I'm following [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/), but am having trouble understanding what's actually going on in step 3.

To break the problem down, I disabled the margins/offsets of the "left" and "right" divs.  This gives you the content at the top, and then the two other elements sitting side by side under it as I would expect **[see P1]**.

I then gradually decreased the margin-left of the "left" div from 0px to -199px which again does what I expect **[see P2]**.

But at -200px (the width of the left element itself), it shoots up to the top **[see P3]**, with the left edge against the right edge of the content.  I would have expected it to just keep going off the edge.

Why does it jump up?  And if there's no conceptual explanation as to why, where does it describe that functionality in the spec?

**Images:**

## P1

[image: Photo 1]

---

## P2

[image: Photo 2]

---

## P3

[image: Photo 3]

Comment: what's the css code you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that both `#content` and `#left` (as well as `#right`) are floated.

Due to the nature of floats, they (or their contents) may overlap. This is well described in [this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats), and is fairly easy to understand. If you apply negative margins to a floated element that's adjacent to another float, it will simply move to its left (similar to having a `left` relative offset), *over* its sibling.

In the section on the [`float` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position), you'll find a list of "the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats." Now, I'm not 100% familiar with the float model, but these points are what I believe to be relevant:

> 2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left [outer edge](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) of the current box must be to the right of the right [outer edge](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.<sup>1</sup>
>
> 7. A left-floating box that has another left-floating box to its left may not have its right outer edge to the right of its containing block's right edge. (Loosely: a left float may not stick out at the right edge, unless it is already as far to the left as possible.) An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
>
> 8. A floating box must be placed as high as possible.
>
> 9. A left-floating box must be put as far to the left as possible, a right-floating box as far to the right as possible. A higher position is preferred over one that is further to the left/right.

So my guess is: a margin of -200px, which is as you say the negative equivalent of the width of the `#left` element itself, causes it to float all the way *up* and to the *right* (rather than to the left) and to hug the edge of the `#center` element which itself is also floated. The right edge of both elements touch each other because of this full, equal negative margin. Consequently, as you continue to increase (or decrease?) the negative margin, you'll see that the `#left` element continues to move to its left.

Note that the padding applied to the `#container` element doesn't interact with the margins; even if you remove the padding on either side or both sides, the margins will interact in the same way.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note also that there's a statement in the section on [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) in the linked section of the spec, that describes the behavior of negative margins, but that is irrelevant as the margins we are concerned with here are horizontal and belong to floated elements, and so are never affected by collapsing.</sub>

Comment: Surely according to rule 2, P3 should not be possible?  The current (purple) box's left edge, is to the left of the earlier-in-document (gray) box's right edge, and its top is not lower than the bottom of the gray box.

Comment: The negative margin actually pushes its left edge to the right, so applying just enough for the width of the current box allows it to fit snugly "on" the right edge of the earlier box. Since it can float "upwards" that way, then the way I see it is that it does so since rule 9 says higher is preferred over further to the left.

Comment: Doesn't the negative left margin push its left edge to the left?  The earlier box is content, which has a width of 100%, so it can't fit snugly on the right edge, as there's no room?  What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: A positive margin would extend a box's outer edge to the left. The outer edge refers to the margin boundaries, not the content or border boundaries.

Comment: If I have a div at the left edge of its containing block, and increase the positive margin of that div, nothing moves to the left.  The div's outer edge remains on the left edge of the containing block, and the content/border boundaries moves to the right.  The way I imagine the margins is as if the div were a man on a boat, and uses his oar to push him out away from the shore, the amount he has pushed is the margin length.  Similarly with a negative margin he just pushes in the opposite direction (which would be tough, given he'll be pushing himself into land, but that's besides the point).

Comment: To clarify the analogy, for negative margins, he digs his oar in the same side of the boat, but pushes under the boat to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: But it disagrees with what you said :P  Looking on the internet, there's loads of info about margins, loads of info about floats, but nothing on what happens when you combine the two.  It looks like it's a bit of a taboo, people use it for layout, but nobody really knows why it works.  The further I dig in css, the less I'm able to like it :(

Comment: Oh whoops... my bad. Indeed, I haven't been able to find much info myself either. It's understandable; even Microsoft made some major booboos in handling margins and floats in IE6 and IE7!

Answer (score 0):

you are using `<h2>` tag for left and right heading but in center you are using `<h1>` that's why you have this problem if you want to solve this problem do one thing 1 use all `<h2>` tag for heading and if you want to use  then apply below class on

```
h1
{
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Where did he say it was a problem?

Comment: what it's mean trouble understanding on question starting